# Filter columns from another spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to filter some columns from another spreadsheet.

```
QUERY({IMPORTRANGE("url-link1","Sheet1!D4:F);IMPORTRANGE("url-link1","Sheet1!H4:J)},....
```

from here I want to filter based on a column e.g "url-link1,"Sheet1!C4:C"=B2.

How to finish the formula?

Thank you.

Comment: So you want to dynamically get the columns described in another cell? (eg. if the cell there is `C4:C` then you get that range) Or maybe on some condition? If so, which?

Comment: Welcome. Please read how to and [share a test sheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/117311) so as you can be easier helped.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
QUERY({IMPORTRANGE("url-link1","Sheet1!D4:F);IMPORTRANGE("url-link1","Sheet1!H4:J)},"select * where Col1 = '"&B2&"'")
```

(Col1 means first column of imported range - here it is Sheet1!D4:D and Sheet1!H4:H)

Comment: The filter criteria is another column from that imported spreadsheet.
I just did this below, but still did not work.

```
=QUERY({IMPORTRANGE("URL-LINK1","Data Value!F3:H");IMPORTRANGE("URL-LINK1","Data Value!L3:N");IMPORTRANGE("URL-LINK1","Data Value!C3:C")},"Select *where Col7 = '"B2"'")
```
I want that Col7 refers to this IMPORTRANGE("URL-LINK1","Data Value!C3:C")

Comment: You are right. I missed that. But now I got "Error
Unable to parse query string for Function QUERY parameter 2: NO_COLUMN: Col7".

Comment: Now I got this "Error
In ARRAY_LITERAL, an Array Literal was missing values for one or more rows."

Comment: I see that you have 3 tables. First is 3 columns. Than You have another 3 columns under it. and third table is just one column under six earlier. It's not going to work this way. If you want 7 columns horizontally, you have to use comma between importranges, not semicolon ; .

Comment: I only changed the semicolon with comma and got this
"Error
Function ARRAY_ROW parameter 2 has mismatched row size. Expected: 110267. Actual: 1"

Comment: Please try to display these columns first with importrange and check if whey have an equal length, and then use query.